# How to detect and execute code when Buy button is pressed in In App Purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to display an `activityIndicator` when the user presses the iTunes buy button to finally purchase a subscription. There is a bit of time processing the purchase and soon as it's done I want to clear the `activityIndicator`.

I've tried different solutions with one of them using `applicationWillResignActive` to detect the iTunes pop up and this is detected right where user is is asked to type in the password. I have also posted a notification when products are requested but still the same thing. Is there a way to know when the iTunes buy button is pressed. Below is my code.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    public static let AppDelegatePurchasesIsProccessing = NSNotification.Name("AppDelegatePurchasesIsProccessing")
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AppDelegatePurchasesIsProccessing, object: self)
      }
}
```

Overlay that is displayed to make purchases

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      self.notifyForUserIsPurchasingProduct {
          self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
     }
 }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      self.notifyForUserHasPurchasedProduct {
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
          self.dismiss(animated: true)
     }
}
```

```
func notifyForUserHasPurchasedProduct(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AppDelegateUserHasPurchasedProductNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (_) in
          action()
    }
}

func notifyForUserIsPurchasingProduct(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AppDelegatePurchasesIsProccessing, object: nil, queue: nil) { (_) in
          action()
     }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just start the activity indicator when the buy button is pressed? Whatever action is triggering the purchase should trigger the activity indicator.

Comment: Yah I've resorted to that. Looks like there isn't a way to detect when the buy button is pressed

Comment: You should see the transaction on the SKPaymentQueue after they buy (or cancel) you can stop your activity indicator there.